# Phalcon installation on Mac by pecl but command doesn't exist

Tags: php, phalcon

I have installed [Phalcon](https://phalcon.io/en-us/download/linux) on macOS Big Sur (v 11.4) using `pecl install phalcon` but the command Phalcon doesn't exit on the terminal.

I have also install the [skeleton of the project](https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/it-it/devtools#installation) by composer, but when I use the Phalcon command on the terminal, doesn't work.

I'm using php 7.4.24

Comment: when you install it what is the output, is there any error?

Comment: I have found the problem. The problem is: when I have installed Phalcon via pecl, after I have to install also the tool develop in order to have the command Phalcon, in reality, in oder to have this command on command line have insert it on .bashrc